# How to install heroku toolbelt using Cygwin

Tags: heroku, github, cygwin, amazon-cloudfront, cloud-hosting

First I'd like to ask for your mercy for my poor English, its not my first language.

I'm starting a new course on [Coursera](https://coursera.org), and the first lecture is all about how to connect to some cloud services which we will be working on during class.

I have an [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) account (which I'm connected to on Cygwin when writing the following commands), heroku & github as well.

We are using [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) (for Win 7 OS) and I was asked to install these two packages using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -y git-core
wget -qo- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

The first one installed smoothley, no problems along the way and when I wrote "which git" it returned a path.

When I wrote the second command it returned nothing... I tried many things and nothing worked.

What can I do in order to install the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/)?

BTW: I have downloaded it by myself from the [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) official site, but couldn't figure out how to relate it to my AWS so it will be aware for its existance on my computer.

Comment: if any of these answered your question, please mark them as correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

tomedemuyt gave a real answer to this question in one of the comments, but building on that, just add this to your .bashrc file and it will work just the same:

```
alias heroku='heroku.bat'
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. only heroku help works, other causes cygwin console to hang.

Answer (score 5):

Hm, if you're in Windows, it might work better to just install the [Heroku toolbelt for Windows](https://toolbelt.heroku.com). I believe it packages cygwin and msysgit.

Comment: When in cygwin, just call `heroku.bat` instead of `heroku`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo in the -q option to wget. You've used a lowercase o and you need the digit 0. This causes wget not to output anything, so the pipe to sh is blank and nothing runs.

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

Comment: I've tried the suggested command above, but the command produced nothing, no effect, no error message. Then I tried removing the command switches -q0-, and not piping to sh, what I got is in the next comment, as I cannot put enough text here.

Comment: $ wget https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh
--2013-07-10 13:00:36--  https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh
Resolving toolbelt.heroku.com (toolbelt.heroku.com)... 174.129.20.208, 174.129.22.35, 184.73.171.204, ...
Connecting to toolbelt.heroku.com (toolbelt.heroku.com)|174.129.20.208|:443... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of `toolbelt.heroku.com' is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of `toolbelt.heroku.com' hasn't got a known issuer.

Comment: Just realize that the original problem is executing on Ubuntu, an AWS instance, and the root cause indeed was the typo of -qo- to -q0-. While my question is executing that command on Cygwin system. It's different.

Comment: add the `--no-check-certificate` flag and then you will have a proper result ... but you may still get stuck later because cygwin doesn't have a sudo command